# Eeek! Can't choose tags anymore (Meta only)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-autocomplete

Maybe Jeff has finally took his vengeance on all of us with his giant S?

> [image]

Those nasty errors happen on page load then whenever I type something in the tag editor. Naturally, they cause I can't choose tags because no tags appear. I can still edit tags and post new questions by manually typing the tags.

Using Chrome latest stable version (30.0.1599.101 m) but doubt it's browser specific.

As a temporary workaround for those with weak memory, you can go to the [tags page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) and the search/filter in there does work.

Comment: Repro: Firefox 24.0 on Win 7, and IE 10 on Win RT. Probably not browser-specific.

Comment: Seems with the &#39; and stylesheet issues recently, there are some changes being rolled out with issues.

Comment: @James there are changes almost daily, many times more than once a day, usually transparent and without bad consequences. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd agree, but seems atm what are usually "standard" rollouts are not without error. Maybe the dev coffee machine is broken?

Comment: There is a coffee machine?

Comment: @Oded you should make them buy one for the office and for each dev working from home. My recommendation: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DY56u.jpg :D

Comment: I am now considering that the fact the I don't drink coffee may be contributing to all these bugs.

Comment: @Oded Meta has been eeekified... :(

Comment: De-eeeeekified enough?

Comment: @Oded nice work, now back to generating more of those! :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower case `s`, so you are safe from Jeff (I believe his is upper case).

I fat fingered a change and committed it - deleting most of the change and keeping an `s` in place.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: But size doesn't matter! Tonberry can insta-kill anything [with his small knife](http://www.kethinov.com/images/psx/ff8/tonberry.png). Anyway, thanks for the quick fix. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd your image is broken :(

Comment: @nijansen try [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VCKW9.png)? :)